# VueJS Data is Not Displaying in template from method return

Tags: vuejs2, lumen

```
/* eslint-disable eol-last */
<template>

<div id="app">
    <ul>
      <li v-for="item in items">  /*  this list is not displaying */
        {{ item.id }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'app',
  data: {
    items: []
  },
  created () {
    this.fetchData()
  },
  methods: {
    fetchData () {
      this.$http.get('http://url/api/users')
        .then(result => {
          this.items = result.data
        })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

this list is not displaying 
i am unable to print this in template. Json returns data but could not access in template.please guide me. Where i am making mistake.

Comment: Adding a `debugger;` before `this.items = result.data` and inspecting `result.data`. Its an array as expected?

Answer (score 2):

The Problem might be that in your Ajax callback you try to assign to THIS.items but THIS has wrong scope. Create a variable before the ajax call 
E.g 
`let self = this;`
And in the ajax cb:
`self.items = response.data;`